# code igniter loading a view at the end of the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

On Ci you have the possibility to load a view directly from the constructor of your controller, I'm loading the header and footer of my page (since it's the same for each function)

```
class Add extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');       
    }

    function whatever()
    {
        //do stuff
    }

 }
```

But this will load the footer view before loading my function, so is there any way to do it without "manually" loading the view at the end of each function ?

Comment: You can use [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) to load the header before your controller function (post_controller_constructor) and the footer afterwards (post_controller).

Comment: @Rocket couldn't he also use the `__destruct()` method as well? Or do i have the wrong concept of this?

Comment: Using **hooks** is a creative approach, but it can get hairy if you don't want a header/footer 100% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

I would add the header/footer in the main view with the data, or use a template library (I use this [one](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/)).

If in main view for function;

```
// in view for html page
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
<h1>My Page</h1>
<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

Comment: +1 for templates.  From the docs: "Template is right for you if you don't like calling header, footer, and other global views from every Controller method." :-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be rendering any views in the constructor. CI Controllers should look more something like this:

```
class Add extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
    }

     function index()
     {
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('home_page');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
     }

     function whatever()
     {
        /*
         * Some logic stuff
         */

        $data_for_view = array(
            'product' => 'thing',
            'foo'     => 'bar'
        );

        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('show_other_stuff', $data_for_view);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
     }

 }
```

Comment: I think he's trying to avoid writing `$this->load->view('header_view');` and `$this->load->view('footer_view');` in *each* method.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this approach:

```
 class Add extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // load some static
        $this->data['page_footer'] = $this->common_model->get_footer();

    }
    private function view_loader () {
        //decide what to load based on local environment
        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
            $this->load->view('profile_view',  $this->data);
        } else {
             $this->load->view('unlogged_view',  $this->data);
        }
    }


    function index()
    {
        $this->data['page_content'] = $this->profile_model->do_stuff();

        // call once in every function. this is the only thing to repeat.
        $this->view_loader();
    }

  }
```